# Processing Maven properties

Tags: maven-3

Sorry for a newbie question.

I've a jar file that contains maven archetype. It goes with a bunch of java/resource files all of which having the following lines at the top

```
#set( $symbol_pound = '#' )
#set( $symbol_dollar = '$' )
#set( $symbol_escape = '\' )
```

These look like some preprocessor directives, but who really does process them? Is there some Maven command I need to run to get these files to valid state?

Answer (score 0):

Those files are velocity files which are handled by the velocity Template system.

The Maven Command is the [mvn archetype:generate](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/) ... to create from those archetypes real projects.